# Rails3 Plugin Date Time When

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A while ago I used a rails3 plugin that let you type in any date / time in a field which was then converted into a normal date / time entry. For example, 9am eat breakfast would be entered in to the calendar.

Despite looking through all my project notes, I cannot find reference to this!

Is there anyone out there who can remember??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Chronic](http://www.rubyinside.com/chronic-natural-date-parsing-for-ruby-229.html)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Jquery.timepicker plug-in instead of Ruby on Rails plug-in? It's really easy to use. Link to jquery.timepicker:

[http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/][1]